# Get result of a button that runs askopenfilename

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I have a button which runs the function `askopenfilename`.

```
filebutton = tk.Button(text = "Choose file ...",
                       command = lambda: openfile())
```

This is the function `openfile`:

```
def openfile():
    filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Excel", "*.xlsx"), 
                                                               ("All files", "*.*")))
    print(filename)
```

Everything runs as expected and the file name is printed to the console. But what I really want is to store the file name into a variable that I can read the data from an excel sheet with pandas like that:

```
Data = pd.read_excel(filename)
```

How can I achieve this? Or is there a better way with other functions?

Comment: You can declare `global` by `global filename`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't retrieve the data in the buttons function call. If you had a global variable,

```
def openfile():
    global filename = tkinter.filedialog.askopenfilename(filetypes = (("Excel", "*.xlsx"), 
                                                               ("All files", "*.*")))
    print(filename)
```

, you could access it from outside the function called by a button.

How I've gotten around this in the past is by using classes. This [tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jBUpjijYtCk) online splits the tkinter program into classes. If you followed this structure you could create a class variable `filename`. This would allow you to manipulate the file within that instance of the class.

Comment: Great, thank you very much! I'm quite new to Python and as a R user I'm not really into classes but that's a great way.

Comment: @TobiSonne If you declare the global before the function you want to use it in, be careful about using it. The function may declare a new local variable with the same name as the global.

Comment: @TobiSonne Also, could you accept my answer as the correct one?